# Bash script not generating the csv file with required content

Tags: bash, shell, perforce

I am running below script in linux environment.

```
#!/bin/bash

export P4PORT="perforceserver:port"
export P4USER="user"
export P4PASSWD=""

# Set the directories to compare
dir1="/home/user1/code1/"
dir2="/home/user1/code2/"

# Set the CSV file to save the comparison results
csvfile="comparison.csv"

# Compare the directories and save the results in the CSV file
diff -rq $dir1 $dir2 | sed 's/: /\t/g' | while read line
do
    file=$(echo $line | awk '{print $2}')
    submitter=$(p4 describe -s $file | awk '/^Change/ {split($0, a, " "); print a[3]}; /^User/ {split($0, a, " "); print a[2]}')
    echo "$line $submitter" >> $csvfile
done
```

`dir2 - data downloaded from Perforce VCS`

**Problem**
above script it is not writing the Perforce submitted owner information into csv file.

Sample expected output:-

```
 Type    code1  code2   Differ  PerforceOwner 
 Files      A.c   A.c      differ  Daniel.u
 Files       b.c   b.c     differ  venket.k
```

Please help me to solve the above problem

Comment: Please show use sample input & expected output in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: ```Files code1 code2 Differ PerforceOwner
    
```

Comment: @Ekam please update the question with the sample inputs and outputs; not everyone will read through comments for the additional details; also, formatting is lost in comments

Comment: This means that either `awk` or `diff` or `p4` do not produce anything on stdout. You could insert a `tee -a p4.out` and `tee -a awk.out` into the pipe which calculates `submitter`. In addition, you could turn on `set -x` for your script.

Comment: [tag:bash] - "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here."

Comment: I don't really know bash scripting, but since this has the #perforce tag on it I'll note that if you're running `p4 describe` with a file arg, that's probably not going to work, and running `p4 describe` and parsing the output is a really painful way of getting information even if you are doing it correctly.  If you want to get the user who submitted the most recent changelist for a given file, that's simply `p4 -F %user% changes -m1 FILE`.  (You might also consider using `p4 diff2` to do the diff server-side.)

Answer (score 1):

`awk` in line 17 uses `white space` as separator, not only the `tab`.
So the content will not contain the expected file names and $2 will stop at the next "white space".

So a diff result like

```
diff -rq "$dir1" "$dir2"
Only in /home/user1/code1/: file name
```

will be processed by your script to the result

```
echo $file
in
```

Here the corrected script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

export P4PORT="perforceserver:port"
export P4USER="user"
export P4PASSWD=""

# Set the directories to compare
dir1="/home/user1/code1/"
dir2="/home/user1/code2/"

# Set the CSV file to save the comparison results
csvfile="comparison.csv"

# Compare the directories and save the results in the CSV file
diff -rq "$dir1" "$dir2" | sed 's/: /\t/g' | while read line
do
    file=$(echo "$line" | awk 'BEGIN{FS = "\t"}{print $2}')
    submitter=$(p4 describe -s "$file" | awk '/^Change/ {split($0, a, " "); print a[3]}; /^User/ {split($0, a, " "); print a[2]}')
    echo "$line $submitter" >> "$csvfile"
done
```

Please note:

- I could not verify line 18 ff (`submitter= ...`) as I don't have `P4`  available and no sample output has been delivered.
- I double-quoted the variables, as they might contain white space. Even this possibly might not be expected, it's a good habit.

If the output is still not as expected, please provide a sample output of

```
p4 describe -s "$file"
```

and typical content of `$dir1` and `$dir2`

Comment: In addition to what's been pointed out by others, the main problem I see is that `p4 describe` is meant to be run on a changelist with an optional file path and it looks like you are trying to run it on just a file path, which should return an error message saying "Invalid Changelist Number"

Comment: Thanks you are right, We have used p4filelog for our requirement